# Open Colorbox with a unique URL in the location bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, popup, colorbox

I have a page that opens a Colorbox pop-up when a link is clicked. When this happens the URL in the location bar stays the same. I want this URL to change so I can link visitors directly to the Colorbox pop-up without guiding them to click on the link instead. [This page](http://www.uu.nl/daretoexcel/#lightbox=http://www.uu.nl/daretoexcel/detail/young-leaders-league) illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish.

So when you look in the URL location bar you see the URL stated above. When you close the pop-up the URL changes to: `http://www.uu.nl/daretoexcel/#`. Again when you open an other window the URL changes to something similar. So I know how to open Colorbox and I got it working. It's just that the URL in the location bar stays the same all the time.

I've looked in their code but I don't quite understand it. I don't want to just copy and paste without knowing what exactly happens.

Comment: take a look at the sources http://www.uu.nl/daretoexcel/wp-content/themes/uu/includes/script/functions.js, particularly for the `hashLoad` function

Comment: No need in extra libs, he just need two events onComplete and onClosed. On first set hash and on second clear it. 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simpler then you think, they just use hash. You can look at examples on colorbox site with events. Get href like this: [How do you get a return value from a colorbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126414/how-do-you-get-a-return-value-from-a-colorbox), then set hash: `document.location.hash` and on close event remove hash.

Comment: Hi webdeveloper, I thought it worked but it just partially did. The URL changes but when I copy paste the link in a new tab colorbox doesn´t open.

Comment: This done by another code, on document ready event, just check param in hash (they use lightbox) and open colorbox, hash is just string, that's why you need to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
$(function() {
$.colorbox({html: "<h1>Welcome</h1>"});
})
```

This will open colorbox on document.ready on the given page. You will probably need to have some class added to the body on the page you want to open it on, you can do this by have a parameter in the url that adds the class like /mypage.html?opencolorbox=true, you then add the class using asp, php or whatever other server side language you are using. Alternatively just have the script above run only on the page the colorbox should open on.

You could also open it to an iframe, or to show inline content like:

```
$(function() {
$.colorbox({href: "login.php"});
})
```

would show the login.php in the colorbox

```
$(function() {
$.colorbox({inline: true, href: "#form"});
})
```

would display the contents of element with the id #form

Comment: Hi Liam, Thank you for your answer. Though this is not what i was really looking for. I will try to clarify it more by editing my main post.